# Why does the existence of non–tempered distributions not contradict the Hahn–Banach Theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Non–tempered distributions are continuous linear functionals on $\mathcal{D}\mathbb{(R^n)}$ (a vector subspace of $\mathscr{S_n}$) which cannot be extended to all of $\mathscr{S_n}$. I think if $f$ is any non–tempered distribution then $f$ grows fast at infinity, implying the existence of the restriction sublinear functional in the Hahn–Banach Theorem cannot be guaranteed. Is my idea right?

Comment: the topology on $\mathcal D$ is not the same as the restriction of the topology on $\mathscr S$ to $\mathcal D$. non-tempered distributions are not continuous if you equip $\mathcal D$ with the subspace topology from $\mathscr S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hahn-Banach states that you can extend a continuous functional that is defined on a subspace of a locally convex space to a continuous functional the entire locally convex space.

The issue here is that while a non-tempered distribution is continuous on the LF-topology of $\mathcal D$, this is not the topology $\mathcal D$ gets as a subspace of $\mathscr S$.